# Commit and Push Enterprise Application Project into BitBucket

Tags: java, git, ejb, bitbucket

I have an Enterprise Application Project, let's call it `iMe`, that splits into 5 different projects:

```
- iMe
- iMeClient
- iMeEJB
- iMeEJBCLient
- iMeWeb
```

How can i push it into BitBucket, without having to create 5 different repositories and committing one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all these five projects into a common root directory and use that as your repository. Then you'll have just one repository. Downside is that you cannot have per-project access controls.

Comment: i guess that will have do it! i really thought there was a way to do it in Eclipse though...

Comment: Once you have created the repo that way, you should be able to commit through Eclipse, even commits that span projects. You can try it locally before you push to BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

As the repositories are different, I don't think that you can do what you want in one command line.
But there is always a solution: you can write a script (in bash ?) that preforms all the pushes.

Comment: Since the iMe project has all the information of the web application, i thought there would be some kind of workaround to get this done in eclipse or via the terminal...

Comment: Yes you can do it via the terminal by launching a .sh script (if you are in linux) that goes trough all the directories and preforms the pushes, instead of going trougth each directory and writing "git ...".